# Given an inductive function, how to calculate?

Tags: functions

Currently having slight difficulty figuring out how to solve this.

Given is;

$$\begin{align}f(0) &= -3\\
f(1)&= 2
\\
f(n) &= f( n - 2 ) + 2  f( n - 1)\end{align}$$

Now, I need to calculate $f(5)$.

I'm not sure how to handle a function like this.
Fill the N's and dissasemble?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To calculate $f(5)$ you can just start using the recursion:
\begin{align*}
  f(2) &= f(0) + 2f(1)\\
   &= -3 + 4\\
   &= 1\\
  f(3) &= f(1) + 2f(2)\\
    &= 2 + 2 \\
    &= 4\\
  f(4) &= f(2) + 2f(3)\\
    &= 1 + 8\\
    &= 9\\
  f(5) &= f(3) + 2f(4)\\
   &= 4 + 18\\
   &= 22.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks a lot! Would it be reliable to just grab f(0) and f(1), getting the difference from that step and just apply that for 5 steps?

Comment: What difference?

Comment: f(0) = -3, f(1) = 2 , difference being 5, then just count up. F(2) = 7, etc.

Comment: But $f(2) - f(1) \ne f(1) - f(0)$.

Comment: Ah, yes, i see what you did there. Not really understanding yet why you'd start with f(2)

Comment: As I can compute $f(2)$ from the given values.

Comment: Doh! Ofcourse! Thanks alot again!